# How to keep recording video when the screen is locked?

Tags: macos, video

I need to record a video continuously and for security reasons I have to lock the screen, because I don't want anyone to be able to access my computer. I have installed a premium application that records video (Camera Record-Camera Recorder), but the problem is that after the screen is locked, only a black screen is recorded.

Do you know any way, or any application that is able to record continuously even when the screen is locked?

Comment: Just wondering, what do you expect it to capture while the screen is locked?

Comment: It's not screen recording, it's video recording. Basically I am trying to use my computer like if it's a surveilance camera.

Comment: If the app does not prevent the system from sleeping you may have to change the sleep timeout to never. Then locking the screen should do just that and not sleep the Mac.\